# Test for default-constructed QFileInfo

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use an optional argument of type `QFileInfo`. What is the canonical way to test if the caller provided a value or if the default was used?

```
// declaration
void foo(QFileInfo fi = QFileInfo());

// definition
void foo(QFileInfo fi)
{
    if ( /* what to test for: "is default" */ ) {

    }
}
```

Usually default-constructed Qt objects have something like `isValid()` or `isEmpty()`. However, there seems no such thing in `QFileInfo`.

One option would be `fi.filePath().isEmpty()`. Is there something better / simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fi.filePath().isEmpty()` seems to be the most straightforward and efficient, given that the effect of calling the default constructor is to create a `QFileInfo` with no file reference.

> #### QFileInfo::QFileInfo()
>
> Constructs an empty QFileInfo object.
>
> Note that an empty QFileInfo object contain no file reference.

Comment: According to the Qt documentation the latter approach is undefined: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#operator-eq-eq

Comment: @oblivioncth: oh right, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can check *if the file exists* after you receive the `QFileInfo` in your function

```
void foo(QFileInfo fi)
{
  if ( fi.exists() && fi.isFile() ) {
    // execute your logic
  }
}
```